# equal? and eql? operator on Fixnum

Tags: ruby

As per definition, `equal?` checks if the two objects are same, where as `eql?` checks if the class are same and values are same.

```
x = 'hi'
y = 'hi'
x.equal? y # => false
x.eql? y # => true

x = 1
y = 1
x.equal? y # => true
x.eql? y # => true
```

Why is the second `x.equal? y` `true`? Aren't `x` and `y` two instances of `Fixnum`? Why doesn't it apply to `Fixnum`/`Float` as shown in the examples above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `x` and `y` do actually refer to the exact same object. Unlike strings, each integer value has only one instance at any given time.

Reference: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Fixnum.html

> There is effectively only one Fixnum object instance for any given integer value [...]

Edit:
To make it a bit more clear, you might want to look at the object_id for these objects:

```
irb(main):001:0> x = 1
=> 1
irb(main):002:0> y = 1
=> 1
irb(main):003:0> x.object_id
=> 3
irb(main):004:0> y.object_id
=> 3 # Same ID as above
irb(main):005:0> x = 'hi'
=> "hi"
irb(main):006:0> y = 'hi'
=> "hi"
irb(main):007:0> x.object_id
=> 70287051883000
irb(main):008:0> y.object_id
=> 70287051869720 # Different ID than X
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question already has been answered but I'll add this about object_id's

`my_string << 'something'` and `my_string.replace 'something'` and bang methods like `my_string.strip!` don't change the object_id that's why you can change a constant's content like `MyString = 'test'`

But `MyString.freeze` will prevent you from the constant beeing mutable.

It's good to try things like this to learn the language :

```
irb(main):024:0> x = '1'
=> "1"
irb(main):025:0> y = x
=> "1"
irb(main):026:0> x.equal? y
=> true
irb(main):027:0> x << 'test'
=> "1test"
irb(main):028:0> y
=> "1test"
irb(main):029:0> nope = nope
=> nil
```